# sql search whilst in a foreach loop or while loop

Tags: php, sql, foreach

Hi firstly heres my code.

```
<?php
function getDatesBetween2Dates($startTime, $endTime) {
$day = 86400;
$format = 'd-m-Y';
$startTime = strtotime($startTime);
$endTime = strtotime($endTime);
$numDays = round(($endTime - $startTime) / $day) + 1;
$days = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $numDays; $i++) {
    $days[] = date($format, ($startTime + ($i * $day)));
}

return $days;
}
///
$days = getDatesBetween2Dates(date('d-m-Y', strtotime('-3 weeks Monday')),date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+2 weeks Sunday')));

foreach($days as $key => $value){


$dayNumber = date('d', strtotime($value));


//echo $value;
echo "<div id=\"day\">
        <div id=\"number\">$dayNumber</div>";

    ////////////sql seearch//\\\/////////
    //Connect to db
    include("../djwbt.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM daysummary WHERE date='$value'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
        $place = $row['place'];
         $invoicedate = $row['date'];
    }
    /////////////end sql search//////////

echo "<div id=\"event\"><a href=\"$value\">$place</a></div>
        </div><!-- end day -->";

}

?>
```

What i am trying to do is show all dates between two points and for each of the dates search my db using the date as a where clause. i have tried putting the search in a few places but im not getting the right results.

this gives me the same result in each date.

e.g. 17th = (empty) as in my db, 18TH = HOME (as in my db), 19th = HOME (not as in my db), 20th = HOME (this continues all the way through fore each)

the link in each fore each works perfectly?

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: i woul suggest you try to use one sql statement instead of a statement inside a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would make one statement that gets all the needed data from your database:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

then use the foreach loop for the results

Note that mysql_ functions are deprecated, Try switching to mysqli_ or PDO

Comment: I cant do it that way because there will be missing entries. The dates are outputting a calendar month style display. Mot weekends will be empty in the db. As for PDO thats my next thing to learn.(Honestly i stop coding for a while and everything changes)

Comment: Sorted it. Problem was with my sql. im using this code (at leaset until i learn PDO)  `code`                                            ////////////sql seearch/////////////
  //Connect to db
  include("../djwbt.php");
  
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM daysummary WHERE date='$value'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $place = $row['place'];
  $invoicedate = $row['date'];  
  /////////////end sql search//////////`code`